# sudo ruby picks system ruby but not rvm installed ruby. it doesnt work even after adding user in exempt_group option in sudoers file

Tags: ruby, centos, rvm, sudoers

after going through some articles I understand that sudo's environment and the commands that it can use are influenced by `/etc/sudoers` file.

this `sudoers` manual - https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html - specifies that users in the group specified by *exempt_group* option are not affected by `secure_path` which basically alters the sudo's PATH

This is how defaults are set in my `/etc/sudoers` file

```
Defaults    always_set_home

Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"

#
# Adding HOME to env_keep may enable a user to run unrestricted
# commands via sudo.
#
# Defaults   env_keep += "HOME"

Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
Defaults    exempt_group=exempt
```

`exempt` is the group on the system that the user is added to.

instead of the `group` on the system, I have also tried using the `group` created by `User_Alias` in `/etc/sudoers` file. this didnt help either.

`sudo ruby -v` - returns 2.0.0

`ruby -v` - returns 2.3.3

how can `sudo` pick `rvm ruby` without modifying secure_path?

`sudo -i` works but in my case the command is a remote ssh command and we dont have access to change that code which triggers the command. please help

Comment: What happens if (and is it possible to?) *uninstall* the system ruby?

Comment: Also, when you say "unable to change the command..." does this mean you're unable to use [`rvmsudo`](https://rvm.io/integration/sudo)?

Comment: ...And lastly, are you bound to `rvm`, or would it be possible to try an alternate version manager? [`rbenv-sudo`](https://github.com/dcarley/rbenv-sudo) may be a viable option.

Comment: Try ` sudo env "PATH=$PATH" ruby -v`. It should give you an idea.